# Openness of inverse limit of quotient mappings

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $(R_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ be a family of equivalence relations on X, whose index set $A$ is directed.
We have canonical mappings $\phi_\alpha : X \to X/R_\alpha$. We assume that $R_\beta$ is finer than $R_\alpha$ when $\beta \geq \alpha$, which means that we have canonical (continuous) mappings $\phi_{\alpha \beta} : X/R_\beta \to X/R_\alpha$.

So $(X/R_\alpha,\phi_{\alpha \beta})$ is an inverse system of topological spaces. We look at the inverse limit $Y$. Let $g : X \to Y$ be the canonical map which is the inverse limit of the $\phi_\alpha : X \to X/R_\alpha$.

Now we make two assumptions :

1. The mappings $\phi_\alpha : X \to X/R_\alpha$ are closed mappings;
2. For each $x \in X$ and each neighborhood $V$ of $x$, there is an index $\alpha$ such that the class of $x$ with respect to $R_\alpha$ is contained in $V$.

Then we must prove that $g : X \to g(X)$ is an open mapping. This is an exercise from Bourbaki's. I'm not able to solve this exercise. Do you have a clue?
Thank you.

Edit. I am completely sorry - I forgot to say that we are looking at the map $X \to g(X)$, not the map $X \to Y$. As was noticed by Mr Scott the result does not hold for the map $X \to Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall answer my own question. In fact it is quite easy but I was not able to do it myself. I had to look for the original article on mathscinet. Turns out this article is written in german. I do not speak german but guessing was not too difficult! If you are interested, check Flachsmeyer, Jürgen - Zur Spektralentwicklung topologischer Räume. The MR is in English.

Anyways here is how it goes. I call $\pi_\alpha$ the projection $Y \to X/R_\alpha$.

1. The family of open subsets $U$ of $X$ which are saturated for some $R_\alpha$ is a basis of the topology. Indeed let $x$ be some point and pick a neighborhood $V$; we can assume that the $R_\alpha$-equivalence class of $x$ is a subset of $V$, then we can shrink $V$ so it becomes $R_\alpha$-saturated (while still being a neighborhood of $x$) because $X \to X/R_\alpha$ is a closed mapping.
2. For any subset $E$ of $X$ let $E^*$ be the subset of $Y$ of all $\xi=(\xi_\alpha)_\alpha$ for which there is some index $\alpha$ such that the equivalence class $\xi_\alpha$ is a subset of $V$.
3. If $E$ is a $R_\alpha$-saturated subset, we have $E^*=\pi_\alpha^{-1}(g_\alpha(E))$. Indeed let $\xi$ belong to $E^*$ so there is some index $\beta$ such that $\xi_\beta \subset E$ and we may assume $\beta \geq \alpha$, then it is easy that $\xi_\alpha \subset E$ as well. This proves $E^* \subset \pi_\alpha^{-1}(\phi_\alpha (E))$. This other inclusion holds because $E$ is $R_\alpha$-saturated.
4. Now if $U$ is an open subset of $X$ which is $R_\alpha$-saturated for some $\alpha$, then $g(U)=g(X) \cap U^*$. Easy to check.

This shows that $g : X \to g(X)$ is an open mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The result appears to be false as stated.

Let $D=\{0,1\}$ have the discrete topology. Endow $D^{\Bbb N}$ with the product topology, and let

$$X=\left\{x\in D^{\Bbb N}:x\text{ is eventually constant}\right\}\;.$$

For $n\in\Bbb N$ define the equivalence relation $\sim_n$ on $X$ as follows: for any $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$, $x\sim_ny$ iff $x_k=y_k$ for all $k<n$. Then $X/\sim_n$ is a discrete space $X_n$ of cardinality $2^n$. Since each $X_n$ is discrete, it’s clear that the quotient maps $\varphi_n:X\to X_n$ are closed. Moreover, if $x\in X$, then $\{\varphi_n^{-1}[\{\varphi_n(x)\}]:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a local base at $x$, so your two conditions are satisfied.

However, $Y=\varprojlim X_n$ is homeomorphic to $D^{\Bbb N}$, so $g[X]$ is only a countable dense subset of $Y$. Every non-empty open subset of $Y$ has cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$, while $g[V]$ is countable for each open $V\subseteq X$, so $g$ cannot be an open map.

Comment: Let $\varphi : Y=\varprojlim X_n \rightarrow D^{\Bbb N}$ be your homeorphism. To which point of $Y$ does correspond the sequence $x$ defined by $x_n = 1 + (-1)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbf{N}$ ? Or did you mean $D^{(\mathbf{N})}$ ?

Comment: @Robert: I don’t know what you mean by $D^{(\Bbb N)}$. Your $x$ corresponds to the sequence $y$ such that $$y_n=\varphi_n(\langle \underbrace{1,0,1,0,\ldots,1+(-1)^{n-1}}_{n\text{ terms}},0,0,0,\ldots\rangle)\;.$$

Comment: $D^{(\Bbb N)}$ is the sequences $D$-valued that take value $1$ only finitely many times, but I mixed up something, yes, you're right.